# c# как сделать программу которая с нуля дает пользователю заполнить двумерный зубчатый массив

Tags: c#, массивы, двумерный-массив

вот допустим программа которая дает пользователю заполнить двумерный массив

```
int v = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[,] array = new int[v,b];

for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < array.GetLength(1); c++)
    {
      array[i,c] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

но я не совсем понимаю как сделать тоже самое с двумерным зубчатым массивом ведь там везде разное количество элементов и для них нужно выделять память. Возможно вопрос глупый но буду рад помощи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jagged arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/arrays#jagged-arrays)

```
int v = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int [][] array = new int[v][];

for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
{
    int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    array[i] = new int[b];
    for (int c = 0; c < b; c++)
       array[i][c] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```